# How to handle dynamic schema and dynamic data in php mysql?

Tags: php, mysql, bigdata, nosql

I am going build a medium scale application, where the requirement is to create web forms dynamically, those forms will be available through a permalink then data entry operator will be entering data in those forms. That data will be used to apply statistical operations on it.

Couple of questions are here.

1. How I can manage the dynamic schema to enter the data, should I be generating a separate table for each form (there can be thousands of forms)?
2. Is there any open source framework in php/codeigniter?
3. Should I think about schema less /Nosql databases?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You may like my presentation [Extensible Data Modeling with MySQL](http://www.slideshare.net/billkarwin/extensible-data-modeling). I talk about requirements and several solutions for dynamic schemas.

- Extra Columns
- Entity-Attribute-Value
- Class Table Inheritance
- Serialized LOB & Inverted Indexes
- Online Schema Changes
- Non-relational databases

Each solution has its own strengths and weaknesses. Knowing about them all gives you more tools to use in a given application.

For storing form data, I'd suggest either the Serialized LOB & Inverted Indexes, or else use a non-relational database that can index fields within a document.

Comment: Thank you for such a great presentation. After reading it I am going to adopt Serialized LOB & Inverted Indexes, but I am worrying about schema updation. If a form is altered, what will happen with the data? And what about the search?

Comment: Additionally, is it possible to create pivot table queries with Serialized LOB & Inverted Indexes technique?

Comment: With Serialized LOB, you can INSERT anything form data you want. Existing data inserted previously is not changed. You must keep the inverted indexes updated manually. Pivot queries would have to be done with the inverted index fields.